# Authenticator app is not working

Tags: google-authenticator

I'm choosing option to add MFA in the Google accounts, scanning barcode, secret is added. Name of the account in the Authenticator is correct. However, when I try to enter the generated code - Google says it's incorrect. The same on all attempts.
Ideas?

UPD I've tried syncing time from the Authenticator - still getting errors

UPD2 Can it be the reason that I previously had Authenticator installed on another phone with different email?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I synced the time and that didn't help. I uninstalled, reinstalled and reconnected the app, and that didn't work either. The device time is correct. I'm not sure what else can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following (taken from [Google Authenticator site](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en#sync):

> **My Google Authenticator codes aren’t working (Android)**
>
> This might be because the time on your Google Authenticator app is not
>   synced correctly.
>
> To make sure that you have the correct time:
>
> 1. Go to the main menu on the Google Authenticator app
> 2. Click Settings
> 3. Click Time correction for codes
> 4. Click Sync now
>
> On the next screen, the app will confirm that the time has been synced, and you should now be able to use your verification codes to sign in. The sync will only affect the internal time of your Google Authenticator app, and will not change your device’s Date & Time settings.

Comment: Yes, I have. No results.

Comment: ah. just seen you've updated your answer to say you've tried this. I'll leave it here but update it if I find anything else that might help.

Comment: Have you checked your device time to ensure it is correct (even a few minutes may affect it). Can you try using [authy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.authy.authy) and see if that works. It's another app that does the same as the Google Authenticator app (Should work exactly the same)

Comment: time is absolutely precise. Is it safe to use this 3rd part application?

Comment: It is a popular alternative to the Google authenticator app, it has between 100,000-500,000 installs and has good reviews. I don't use it myself but it appears to be a good app. I can't promise that it's 100% safe though in the same way I can't guarantee any app is safe.

Comment: Authy doesn't work too

Answer (score 1):

Your codes are most likely TOTP codes meaning they are time based. The simple fix is to to make sure all your devices are using the correct timezone (time is setup correctly). If the time on your devices are correct, but you are still having problems its most likely the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar trouble when I got a new phone. The app was installed on the new device (because apps were synced with the cloud) and it created codes but they were rejected by the google services on a PC. This helped:

- on the PC: log in to google once with a different method
- go to account settings > security > login to google > 2-step-verification > Authenticator App > change smartphone > android => a QR code is shown.
- on the smartphone: open Google Authenticator > click on "+" button > scan barcode
- scan the QR code from the PC

this created a new account in the authenticator app, creating different (correct) codes